Is it okay for wall AC unit to use a different model’s grille / rear louver panel
I have a friedrich sleeve & grille but ordered a koldfront AC unit. I don’t want to remove the grille since it’s already installed/sealed and trying to keep the self install simple. Would the AC unit work okay without the correct grille? Any risk of fire hazard or inefficiency? Also in the instructions it says the koldfront grille can be mounted on the unit. In that case i could have two grilles (inner most one is correct koldfront and outer grille is the original). Is that preferable to koldfront unit (w/o grille) with just the friedrich grille? How important are these air flow vents directions?




Remove the Koldfront grill and install into the existing opening. I suspect the diverters on the Koldfront have more to do with noise to the outside than efficiency.

It'll be fine.  YMMV on louver direction, though.  You may find that it blows in an undesired direction.  If you don't think that's a concern, don't worry about it.
